# Boundedness of Newtonian potential

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Let $\Omega$ be an open domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The Newtonian potential of a function $f$ is the convolution
$$ Nf(x) = \int_\Omega \Gamma(x-y)f(y)\, dy $$
where $\Gamma$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace equation.
I want to show that the Newton potential is a bounded map from $L^p(\Omega$) to itself for $1\leq p < \infty$.
I know from lemma 7.12 of Gilbarg-Trudinger *Elliptic partial differential equation of second order* that for $n>2$ it is true.
Now my question is for $n=2$.
In this case $N:L^p(\Omega)\to L^p(\Omega)$ become
$$ Nf(x) = \int_\Omega \log|x-y|f(y)\, dy. $$
How can I show that this operator is bounded ?

Comment: Hint: Use Young’s convolution inequality and the fact that the kernel $\log x \in L^1(\Omega)$, for bounded $\Omega$.

Comment: If the domain is bounded, yes.

Comment: +1 upvoting for the nonbounded region aspect.